# How to find sum of first three values and compare it with another property

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui, assertion

This is my json response and I need to  sum of first 3 values and compare it with total value in the SOAPUI.

```
{
   "major": 21,
   "minor": 1,
   "critical": 3,
   "total": 25
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself at all? Please share it with us

Comment: Basu Raj, please check the solution to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Script Assertion` for the REST Request Test step as shown below:

Script:

```
assert context.response, 'Response is empty or null'

//Parse the json
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(context.response)

//Check if sum of 3 properties equal to toal
assert json.total == json.with { major + minor + critical}
```

Here is the standalone version of the same which you can try it online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/m0C8Ww)</kbd>